# Meaning of this Samuel Johnson quote

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, quotes

"The use of travelling is to regulate imagination by reality and instead of thinking how things may be to see them as they are." - Samuel Johnson

Comment: What is mysterious about Johnson's meaning?

Answer (score 5):

It is advice not to sit around in one locality and speculate (with your unfettered imagination) about the nature of the world, but rather to travel,  thus gaining direct knowledge and experiences that establish realistic experiential boundaries on your thinking, i.e. "regulating" or constraining your world view.